# Did Feeras Antoon cheat porn star Mia Khalifa up to number 1 on PornHub?

Tags: pornography

Recently, a reputable Lebanese [talk show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJL-BB9UJh8) discussed trendy lebanese adult performer, [Mia Khalifa](http://www.mirror.co.uk/3am/celebrity-news/who-mia-khalifa-everything-you-4921882). They claimed that she is supported by her husband, Feras Antoon, a Syrian man she met in the Middle East. They claimed he owns PornHub, a popular porn tube site with [Alexa rank 74](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/pornhub.com), and cheated the system to bring her up to the top PornHub rank.

Pornhub [tweeted](https://twitter.com/miakhalifa/status/549074594103955456)

> Congrats @MiaKhalifa currently the #1 ranked pornstar on Pornhub
>   taking the crown from Lisa Ann 》》

Many other people were skeptical that the ranking was obtained fairly. For example, [this article](http://www.mirror.co.uk/3am/celebrity-news/who-mia-khalifa-everything-you-4921882) said:

> Mia Khalifa is currently the number one porn star on website PornHub,
>   despite only starting making films a few months ago.

In the video, [ميا خليفة تبناها سوري](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJL-BB9UJh8) ("Mia Khalifa adopted by a Syrian"), one journalist made these claims of dishonesty, without revealing her sources.

What was bizarre to me, is that they claimed that Feeras Antoon is the owner and CEO of MindGeek. They showed a Facebook profile to support their claim that he's CEO of ManWin.

I find it hart to believe that [MindGeek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MindGeek) (a billion-dollar company which owns: PornHub, YouPorn, RedTube and Babes.com Brazzers, Digital Playground, Reality Kings, Twistys, and Men.com, along with other 100 professional sites) would be support dishonestly tweaking the ranking system.

I am skeptical mainly about two claims here:

1) Feeras Antoon funded Mia Khalifa and helped her cheat her way to number 1 on PornHub.

2) Feeras Antoon is actually the CEO and owner of MindGeek.

If we prove claim #2 is false we would know that claim #1 is false too.

Answer (score 2):

### Feeras Antoon is actually the CEO and owner of MindGeek

Feeras Antoon is ([according to his LinkedIn profile](https://ca.linkedin.com/pub/feras-antoon/26/930/729)) currently CEO at Manwin Canada.

According to [this 2012 article in *Die Welt*](http://www.welt.de/wirtschaft/webwelt/article112037545/YouPorn-lebt-weiter-auch-ohne-seinen-Chef.html) he controls the largest number of the approximately 1000 Manwin employees and seems to have acted to keep the whole enterprise running while Fabian Thylmann was "sitting in custody".

> Dass die Seiten ohne Störung weiterbetrieben werden, dürfte vor allem an Feras Antoon liegen, dem Geschäftsführer der kanadischen Manwin-Filiale. Antoon hat das Kommando über den größten Teil der insgesamt rund 1000 Mitarbeiter der Manwin-Gruppe.

Translated from the German by Google Chrome:

> That the sides will continue to operate without interference, probably due to Feras Antoon, CEO of the Canadian Manwin branch. Antoon has command of the largest of the approximately 1,000 employees of Manwin group.

So even if he is not CEO and owner of MindGeek, he seems to be one its top leaders.

Comment: This answers claim #2, but since you proved it to be true we still need an answer for claim #1: did he manipulate the rating system to bring Mia Khalifa to the top position?

Comment: "That the sites continue to operate without interference is probably mostly due to Feras Antoon, CEO of the Canadian Manwin branch." Is I think a sightly better  translation of the first sentence.